# socket.io and async events

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, mongoose, socket.io

I'm using socket.io and mongoose in my express server.

My socket is listening for events using the following code:

```
socket.on('do something', async () => {
  try {
    await doA();
    doX();
    await doB();
    doY();
    await doC();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

`doA`, `doB` and `doC` are async operations that writes on database using mongoose, but in general they can be any method returning a promise.

I want that 'do something' runs synchronously.
If the event queue processes more events at the same time I have consistency problems in my mongodb.

In other words if the server receives two 'do something' events, I want that the second event received is processed only when the first event is fully processed (after the `await doC`). Unfortunately the 'do something' callback is async.

How to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to implement a queue by adding the functions you want to run to an array, and then running them one by one. I've created an example below.

```js
let queue = [];
let running = false;

const delay = (t, v) => {
   return new Promise((resolve) => { 
       setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, "Returned value from Promise"), t)
   });
}

const onSocketEvent = async () => {
  console.log("Got event");
  if (!running) {
    console.log("Nothing in queue, fire right away");
    return doStuff();
  }
  // There's something in the queue, so add it to it
  console.log("Queuing item")
  queue.push(doStuff);
}

const doStuff = async () => {
  running = true;
  const promiseResult = await delay(2000);
  console.log(promiseResult);
  
  if (queue.length > 0) {
    console.log("There's more in the queue, run the next one now")
    queue.shift()();
  } else {
    console.log("Queue empty!")
    running = false;
  } 
}

onSocketEvent();
setTimeout(() => onSocketEvent(), 1000);
setTimeout(() => onSocketEvent(), 1500);
setTimeout(() => onSocketEvent(), 2000);
setTimeout(() => onSocketEvent(), 2500);
```

Comment: Very elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a delay between each await. This will prevent deadlocks from occurring and fix your issue. For such things, I would suggest using the [Caolan's](https://github.com/caolan/async) async library.

Task delay example:

```
setTimeout(function() { your_function(); }, 5000); // 5 seconds
```

If your function has no parameters and no explicit receiver, you can call directly `setTimeout(func, 5000)`

Useful [jQuery timers plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/timer/)

Comment: I'm not sure I completetly understand you answer. Do you mean I have to remove the *async* keyword? In this case I couldn't await anything.

Comment: Sorry, I meant something a long the lines of adding a small delay. Also, maybe making it a boolean method? If the first event passes successfully, return a true, and only then, process the second event